# How to integrate Storyblok with Shopify's hydrogen

Tags: storyblok, shopify-hydrogen

I'm trying to integrate Storyblok with Shopify Hydrogen and I can't find any examples or documentation anywhere on how to do it. I've integrated Storyblok with next.js before, so I have basic storyblok knowledge, but I'm new to Hydrogen and can't figure out where/how to even make the call to get my Storyblok content. Does anyone know of any documentation I've overlooked or have some sample code I could learn from?

I'm using the starter project provided by the Hydrogen team as my base https://stackblitz.com/edit/shopify-hydrogen-k7bmor?file=README.md&title=Hydrogen

Answer (score 1):

It’s not so different to integrating NextJS as they are both React based frameworks, you can use the same principles replacing Next components for Hydrogen’s.

In the Hydrogen demo you can see that it uses GraphQL queries to pass data from Shopify to the frontend. You can use this same principle to pass data from your CMS to the frontend, but using Storyblok’s api instead.

Take a look through the NextJS Storyblok set up and use those ideas on where to include your api config and calls. https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-and-render-blog-articles-in-storyblok-and-next-js

I’m currently working on a storefront with Hydrogen using Strapi as the CMS and I have created a folder for my api calls, I then reference the api needed in say my hero banner component or my news section component and iterate through the data that way. I hope this helps in some way.